# Being able to login even though login is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase

I am using Firebase for Login/Sign Up authentication but I ran into a problem. I got everything to set up and it works fine, but I am having a bit of an issue with the login part.

Here's my code:

```
@IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainSegue", sender: self) //Issue
}
```

What's wrong is that when the email or the password is incorrect, it will still perform the segue. I tried:

```
@IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainSegue", sender: self) //Error Line
        }
    })
```

But I get an error:

> Implicit use of ‘self’ in closure, use ‘self.’ to capture semantics explicit.

Is there a better way of bring the user to the next UI if and only if login was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you have shared

```
    @IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainSegue", sender: self) //Issue
}
```

The `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` method is being called within the @IBAction and not inside the completion handler of the signIn(withEmail:password:completion) method. Thus, regardless of what is written or executed in the latter, your `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` will be called. Try modifying the code to the following

```
    @IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainSegue", sender: self) 
            }
        })
    }
```

Keep in mind that, because the logic is being executed in a closure, you need to specify the `self.` prefix before methods and variables!

Answer (score 1):

Any `variables` or `methods` used inside of block needs to  use of `‘self’`.

```
@IBAction func clickLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

    if let error = error {

        print(error.localizedDescription)


    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMainSegue", sender: self) //Error Line
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes in the else part everytime your API hits successfully even if the login credentials are wrong.

The FIRAuth API must be returning some data when it gets hit, for example a string or dictionary named "success" = 1 or 0. Check in ur else part for the success to be true or false. false being wrong credentials and true being correct credentials.

The error part gets executed when there is any error in hitting the API itself like network error or the API's parameters being in wrong format or any other error.

In your case its getting hit and returning a result too. You have to check the result dictionary if your user did get logged in or not and segue onto the next controller based on that result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is how I do my login.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { user, error in
        if error == nil {
            print("Successfully Logged IN \(user!)")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signedIn", sender: self)
        }
    })
```

This just tests if there is no error with the signing in process, then performs the segue. I haven't had any trouble with it, and it seems to work great.